# Integrating new designs into an old rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I was asked to integrate new designs into an old app, but the designs are completely different from what there is now. Due to the functionalities already there in the app, I had to integrate the design into it. Starting with the homepage, I replaced all the html.erb files but there is a bootstrap theme which is consistent in the background. I also have to integrate new js into the app. Can anyone please guide a newbie through this? Been at it since 2 days and I don't even know where I am going wrong. Working with rails 3.2.13. Any suggestions or advice for the same would be very much welcome too. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Any further information/details needed, will be provided on asking.

Comment: Don't know if there's a guide on this but there should be , do you know the structure of designs in your app ?

Comment: Yes , but i am confused what all shall i remove . Not good with integrating designs :(

Comment: There's sass , less everything included . Which makes it even further confusing :|

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how proficient you are with Rails, but the bottom line is this:

> Rails is an [MVC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), meaning all the `interface` stuff is
>   contained in the `views` part of the app
>
> When you want to change the look of the `homepage`, all you need to do
>   is go into `app/views/home_controller/index.html.erb` and edit te
>   file. That will allow you to change the HTML; the CSS is simply about
>   replacing / changing the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`
>   files

If you're trying to integrate bootstrap, I would personally:

> - remove all the CSS (depending on how much changing you wish to do)
> - add the bootstrap CSS, apply fixes to the layout files (in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`)
> - begin to re-design the interface for each view using boot

This is obviously very generalised. Maybe you can post some code to give us an idea as to what you're struggling with directly?

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Rich for the advice , i made some changes into app/views/layout/application.html.erb - This is when i started seeing changes in homepage . But the problem arising now is the same thing is coming on all pages .

Comment: Yep - the layout is designed to give you a standard "template" for the base HTML. The `views` load into the layout, meaning if you change anything in the layout, it will affect all the views which use it. Are you new to Rails? If so, I'll give you some tips on how to do this

Comment: Yes , please do help me out with this . Not entirely new to rails , but dis is my first time integrating a new design . Earlier i always used to start from scratch .

Comment: Ok , i was able to do the css part . Images are loading fine now . Stuck with js , any pointers ??

Comment: What's up with your JS? Does it not load?

Comment: Nope , this is the error that keeps coming - ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/jquery.fancybox.js")

Comment: I have kept the js files under app/assets/javascripts

Comment: Okay thanks for the info - how are you calling the javascript files?

Comment: Firstly , i did a require for all the js files in application.js and then in the top of html.erb file i do this - <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/fancybox.js"></script>

Comment: When you say you can load up the `stylesheet_link_tag` in `html.erb` - do you mean `application.html.erb`? If you're trying to load `javascript` files, you'll have to use `<%= javascript_include_tag "your_js" %>` -- this will load the files from `/app/assets/javascripts/_____.js`

Comment: ok , trying it out now . Earlier i had just mentioned - <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> . I used to think it loads all the js //required under it

Comment: Well it will load what you include in the //require parts of the `application.js` - that will be the correct way to do it

Comment: Okay, back to fundamentals - what's the error you're getting? Your JS is not showing?

Comment: Yes , all the fade in effects and drop downs aren't viewable , those effects do work in normal html format before integrating into app .

Comment: Right - so are you getting any errors in your browser console? This will tell you if the JS is not loaded, or any other error which shows

Comment: Using firebug i guess , that's what you want to say ?

Comment: Yep :) You need to see why those JS functions aren't being called - either the files aren't present or there's another error somewhere else

Comment: It's not getting the js files , i am out of ideas where to put them so the homepage gets it .